# C++ Template Function Optimizations Fail

Tags: c++, templates, optimization

From my understanding, a branch that is evaluated at compile-time to be false won't be taken. In the following code, shouldn't the compiler discard the block containing the line that is causing the error?

```
#include <iostream>

template<int i1, int i2>
void TemplateFunc()
{
    std::cout << i1 << std::endl;
    if(i2 > 0)
    {
        std::cout << i2 << std::endl;
        // The following causes an error
        // "cannot allocate an array of constant size 0"
        int someThing[i2] = {276};
        std::cout << someThing[i2/2] << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    TemplateFunc<1,2>();
    TemplateFunc<3,0>();
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried this with VS 2012, g++ (on coliru with "g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out") and using nvcc (with similar code in a cuda kernel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Templates only end up confusing matters. Take a simpler example.

```
int main() {
  if (0) {
    int array[0];
  }
}
```

This causes a compile-time diagnostic (on a conforming implementation). By your logic, it shouldn't, because the `if` block is never taken.

In theory, the check whether `0` is zero takes place at run-time, so the compiler has to account for the possibility that the branch *might* be taken.

In practice, compilers do optimise away constant conditions, but that's under the as-if rule, which effectively states that optimisations must not change the meaning of the program. The unoptimised program would have an error that would be diagnosed at compile-time. Therefore, the optimised program still has an error that gets diagnosed at compile-time.

There are some ways to include checks that *must* be performed at compile-time. One method would be a template partial specialisation, and removing the offending code from the specialisation that would be taken if `i2` is not positive:

```
template<int i1, int i2, bool i2_is_positive>
struct TemplateFuncImpl;

template<int i1, int i2>
struct TemplateFuncImpl<i1, i2, false> {
  static void Impl() {
    std::cout << i1 << std::endl;
  }
};

template<int i1, int i2>
struct TemplateFuncImpl<i1, i2, true> {
  static void Impl() {
    std::cout << i1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << i2 << std::endl;
    int someThing[i2] = {276};
    std::cout << someThing[i2/2] << std::endl;
  }
};

template<int i1, int i2>
void TemplateFunc()
{
    TemplateFuncImpl<i1, i2, (i2 > 0)>::Impl();
}
```

This is admittedly very verbose, so it may not be something you actually want to use. Unfortunately, there is no simple method. @Columbo mentions there have been proposals for a variant of the `if` statement that *would* be forced to run at compile-time, but nothing that actually made it into the standard.

Comment: I would also mention static if. +1

Comment: @Columbo Is there such a thing? I know there have been proposals for it, but I'm not aware of them being accepted.

Comment: There isn't such a thing officially, no. Still it was considered and would constitute exactly what the OP seems to want. (I'm just saying I'd mention it, nothing important)

Comment: @Columbo Managed to figure out a more helpful way to include that in my answer, I think. :) Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the extra mile, but as you pointed out, that's very verbose and for the sake of the test I am writing, I don't want to restructure the various elements of the program.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have misunderstood the way the compiler works. It might be free to discard the check when the template is instantiated, but if the compiler is going to instantiate the template it must compile in the first place. Since it doesn't compile, and there are no alternative templates to use, it will fail with a compilation error.

Had this been a template *class* you could have made this possible with an partial specialization:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int i1, int i2>
class TemplateFunc {
public:
  void operator()() {
    ...code with an if...
  }
};

template<int i1>
class TemplateFunc<i1, 0> {
public:
  void operator()() {
    ...code without and if...
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)  
{
  TemplateFunc<1,2>()();
  TemplateFunc<3,0>()();
  return 0;
}
```

In this code, the template with an if will not be selected by compiler because of the specialization, and thus no compilation error will occur. But for functions this method is simply not allowed by todays standards.

Comment: A template function can delegate to a static method of a template class, where that template class can be specialised. I had just included that in my answer. :) BTW, `i2` could also be negative, so I didn't simply specialise for the `i2 == 0` case.

Comment: @hvd Does the static function offer anything that operator() does not? And yes one could add three states as a third template argument to support negative values also, but IMO our solutions are both overkill enough as it is.

Comment: `TemplateFunc<1,2>()` does not call your `operator()`. It merely constructs a `TemplateFunc<1,2>` object. To call your `operator()`, you'd need to write `TemplateFunc<1,2>()()`, which I wanted to avoid.